# How to reduce/reset the window-size of the checkstyle preferences in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, window, preferences, checkstyle

I'm using Checkstyle in Eclipse (installed on LinuxMint `17.2`).

The table showing the available checkstyle-configurations more that `3500px`. When I try to reduce the window-size, a horizontal scrollbar appears, and the Buttons `Edit`, `Properties`,... remain on the right side.

[image: Window with checkstyle-preferences in eclipse.]

Is there a way to reduce the window-size and get rid of the horizontal scrollbar?